# How to avoid strict stubbing argument mismatch in java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have an object like

```
@SuperBuilder(setterPrefix = "set", toBuilder = true;
class Person {
  private final String name;
  private final boolean active;

}
```

I use this object in a method like

```
public SomeType doSomething(Long id) {
   Person person = personService.getPersonById(id);
   Person updatedPerson = updatePerson(person);
   validationService.isValid(updatedPerson);
    ......
}

private Person updatePerson(Person person) {
  person.toBuilder()
        .setActive(true)
        .build();
}
```

But when I test this method I get a strict stubbing argument mismatch

```
void test() {
 Person person = Person.builder()
   .setName("Name")
   .build();
 Person updatedPerson = Person.builder()
   .setName("Name")
   .setActive(true)
   .build();
when(personService.getPersonById(1L)).thenReturn(person);
when(validationService.isValid(updatedPerson)).thenReturn(false);
```

.......

Can someone tell me how to avoid this problem- and create a correct argument?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just use lenient() for your when() which cause exception

Comment: does your Person class have equals() and hashCode() methods?

Comment: Where are `getPersonById` and `isValid` called? Where does your test call `doSomething()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2-3 options for solving this issue. The easiest solution would be to simply override the `equals` method from the `Person` class (or simply add lombok's `@EqualsAndHashcode` - but this will affect your production code (not only the test itself).

Alternatively, you can use a more generic Mokito matcher here are some examples that would work:

```java
// check solely based on name/active fields
when(validationService.isValid(
      ArgumentMatchers.argThat(p -> p.getName().equals("Name")))
  )
  .thenReturn(true);

// or
when(validationService.isValid(Mockito.any(Person.class)))
  .thenReturn(true);

// or simply
when(validationService.isValid(Mockito.any()))
  .thenReturn(true);
```

Lastly, if validationService is not doing any I/O, you can try to write the code/test in such a way that mocking it is not necessary. In other words, if `validationService.isValid(p)` is just checking some state, maybe you can use the actual object and decide from `validationService` whether to return a valid or invalid `Person` object.

In my opinion, the fewer mocks the better... I would personally try this last approach if possible.